# unbind and off doesn't work before call ajax-Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an element with class`.btn-confirm` and handel click event like this in `MasterLayout (ASP.NET MVC)`

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-confirm', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#url').data('deleteurl'),
        type: "POST",
        data: { code: $('.btn-confirm').data('code') },
        success: function (data) {
                ShowMessage(data.message, 'success');
        },
        error: function (responce) {
            ShowMessage('error', 'error');
        }
    });
});
```

and I want override this event in Other Page like this :

```
 $('.btn-confirm').unbind('click');
    $('.btn-confirm').off('click');
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-confirm', function () 
{
    ...}
```

but when I clicked on button , run two functions , I want disable first event handle.

I used `unbind` and `off` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind the event on `document` you must then also unbind it on `document`

```
$(document).off('click', '.btn-confirm');
$(document).on ('click', '.btn-confirm', ...new function...
```

Comment: @UthmanRahimi construct a simple example to see that it works... There must be something else what is going on on your page... You could debug the `on` and `off` calls and look what event handlers are attached at the button: https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Events